# Python: Is it a good idea to pass the logger around?

Tags: python, logging

My API of a web server logs like this:

```
started
started
succeeded
failed
```

That's two requests received at the same time. It's hard to tell which one succeeded or failed. To separate requests from each other, I created a random number for each and used it as the name of the logger

```py
logger = logging.getLogger(random_number)
```

The logs became

```
[111] started
[222] started
[111] succeeded
[222] failed
```

Looks clear now, but the problem of this approach is that I have to pass the logger to every related class like this:

```py
def __init__(self, logger):
    self._logger = logger
```

So the question is:

1. Is this the best way to log context of each request?
2. If so, is it a good idea to pass the logger around? Is there any way to make the code less verbose?

Comment: If I understand correctly, each log entry comes from a different class instance ?

Answer (score 0):

You should not generate a new logger for each request. You should identify a unique attribute of a request (client IP, URL, session ID, some cookie token...) and add it to the log statement. That way you'll be able to link different log entries of a single request in the log output.

Also, logs should not be passed around. Attribute `name` from `logging.getLogger(name)` should be used to obtain the same logger from different locations in the code.

Best to read up on logging in more detail, e.g. here https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html where you can find maybe a useful example with the client IP:

```
FORMAT = '%(asctime)-15s %(clientip)s %(user)-8s %(message)s'
logging.basicConfig(format=FORMAT)
d = {'clientip': '192.168.0.1', 'user': 'fbloggs'}
logger = logging.getLogger('tcpserver')
logger.warning('Protocol problem: %s', 'connection reset', extra=d)
```

Comment: Okay. If I create a session ID for each request, is there any way to include it in every line of code? Because I hope all the logs would be in a format like this "[session ID] message" without having to pass the session ID to every class.